# event.target не работает по отношению к кнопке

Tags: javascript

Клик был совершён на кнопке. В консоле не должно быть ошибки, но она есть. В чём дело?

```js
function add(event){
 console.log(event.target)
}
```

```css
  div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 25px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="div">Hi!
  <button id="button" onclick="add()">Add button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметр в функцию за Вас должен Пушкин передавать :)?

```js
function add(event){
 console.log(event.target)
}
```

```css
  div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 25px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="div">Hi!
  <button id="button" onclick="add(event)">Add button</button>
</div>
```

или вот так

```js
function add(event){
 console.log(event.target)
}
//document.getElementById("button").onclick = add;
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", add);
```

```css
  div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 25px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="div">Hi!
  <button id="button">Add button</button>
</div>
```